# collapsing and presentation of group

Tags: group-theory

Let $X_{2n} = \langle x,y \mid x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2 \rangle$

Dummit and Foote show $x^3 = 1$ follows from this presentation (I understand that derivation) and then this implies $\lvert X_{2n}\rvert \le 6$ for any n "from the discussion above". This is page 27 of my edition.

This latter part I cannot understand and I do not see the discussion D&F refer to. 
Can someone explain why $x^3 = 1 \implies \lvert X_{2n}\rvert \le 6$ ?

Comment: I just looked at D&F. It says at most $6$. Maybe you should read the book more cautiously.

Comment: You are entirely right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above discussion refers to the first lines of page 27, where the authors prove that every element of $X_{2n}$ can be written as $y^kx^i$. As $x^3=y^2=1$, one can choose $k$ between $0,1$ and $i$ between $0,1,2$. So, $X_{2n}$ has at most $6$ elements.

Comment: for n=1, won't x=1, and for n=2, won't ord(x)=2?  In general, why does $x \ne 1$ follow from the notation?  Also, I think the fact you are using here has not been presented by D&F at this point in the text - but maybe not.

Comment: Edited the solution accordingly

Comment: Perfect explanation. I'm totally clear on it now thank you